# Mega upload does not upload file and test location

Tags: file-uploads, devdemon

I have two issues with Mega upload. I use EE 2.10.1 and Mega Upload 2.5.5.

1. I added a MU field to a channel. When I click on 'select file', nothing happens. I don't even get an error in the console. Are there known add-ons that interfere with MU or is it a problem in MU itself?
2. In the field properties you can choose an upload location and test it with the link 'test location'. When I click the link I get the error $.fancybox is undefined in my console. This is because the module tries to load fancybox from EE's core, but it doesn't exist there anymore. I solved this by adding fancybox to the themes folder and added js and css with the add_to_head function. Also I changed

   $.fancybox.showActivity();

to

```
$.fancybox.showLoading();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong. The url to the upload directory was not correctly set.